# Match Array to String in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, search, match

I am trying to get search result from mongoDB by matching Array of String to particular String Object in MogoDB Document.
My Sample MongoDb Document.

```
"Notedisp" : {
   "NoteID" : NumberLong(100281),
   "NoteTitle" : null,
   "NoteContent" : "In mathematics, the Pythagorean theorem theorem, also known as Pythagoras's theorem, is a relation in Euclidean geometry among the three sides of a right triangle. It states that the square of the hypotenuse (the side opposite the right angle) is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides. The theorem can be written as an equation relating the lengths of the sides a, b and c, often called the \"Pythagorean equation\"\r\n\r\na^2 + b^2 = c^2 ,\r\nwhere c represents the length of the hypotenuse and a and b the lengths of the triangle's other two sides.",       
 },
```

I have already tried following code.

```
var listTearm = ["what","is","Pythagorean","theorem"]
var filter = (builder.AnyIn("Notedisp.NoteContent", listTearm)
```

In above code "Notedisp.NoteContent" is a string Object in MongoDB Document and it is returning empty string. So is there any specific way from which I can match String to MogoDb document and which can return specific data.

Comment: Maybe this will get you on the right track?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#match-any-of-the-search-terms

Answer (score 0):

With a simplified object,

```
public class Note
{
  [BsonId] public long Id { get; set; }
  [BsonElement("content")] public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

first you have to create a text index on your collection:

```
  IndexKeysDefinition<Note> keys = "{ content: \"text\" }";
  string contentTextSearchIndex = await _collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(keys);
```

then match any of the search terms with the `$text` operator:

```
var fdb = Builders<Note>.Filter;
var cursor = await _collection.FindAsync(fdb.Text("what is Pythagorean theorem"));
var docs = await cursor.ToListAsync();
```